# Check if umbraco user can see published content

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have `Umbraco` User Id (not current user id) and published content Id, how can I check that user is able to see this content?
  I found this api:

```
  Access.HasAccess(int documentId, memberId)
```

But it`s marked as obsolete. Any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at  ApplicationContext.Current.Services.PublicAccessService.HasAccess (remember the "using Umbraco.Core.Services")

Answer (score 0):

For current member you should user the UmbracoHelper.MemberHasAccess method

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/umbracohelper/

So as an example you could something like this to display the children of the current page the member has access to:

```
var children = Model.Content.Children.Where(c => Umbraco.MemberHasAccess(c.Path));
```

But you say it's not for the current member so can you extend you questions to understand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
int memberId;
int nodeId;


var publicAccessService  = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.PublicAccessService;
var contentService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
var memberService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService;

var member = memberService.GetById(memberId);
var rolesList = Roles.GetRolesForUser(member.Username);


if(publicAccessService.HasAccess(nodeId, contentService, rolesList))
{
    // has access
}
{
    // does NOT have access
}
```